# Passport expired - how can I attend a funeral in Canada?

Tags: canada, us-citizens

I have a funeral of a family member in Canada and my passport has expired. Is there a way I can still go to the funeral? If so, what do I need to do? I am a U.S. citizen.

Comment: Many countries offer express passport services, have  look at that.

Comment: The obvious response is 'get a new passport'. If you want something more specific you need to explain why that's problematic.

Comment: Are you in the US or will you be travelling from a third country?

Comment: https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/passports/apply-renew-passport/hurry.html

Answer (score 6):

I presume that you are not in Canada, because if you were you would not be asking the question.

1. If you are a Canadian or US citizen and you are in the US, you can cross into Canada *at a land border* with proof of identity and proof of citizenship.  For example, you might use a driver's license for the former and a birth certificate for the latter.  This approach is not without its problems, however, including potential difficulties returning to the US.  The difficulties and their resolutions depend on your citizenship.
2. In any other circumstance, or if you must fly from the US to Canada, you need to get a new passport.  If you are a US citizen you can get same-day service at a passport agency.  Other countries may similarly have expedited or emergency service available.

Comment: Many "same day"/"emergency"/"temporary" passports aren't accepted for entry to each country as they often don't have an electronic chip and short validity (if it is valid only for 6 months it won't qualify or "6 months after departure date") depending on citizenship you thus might need an additional emergency visa from Canada

Comment: @johannes same-day service at a US passport center is a fully valid regular passport.  Also, Canada has no six-month rule, so that is not a concern here.  Furthermore, Canada appears to accept any sort of valid passport for eTA, and they also accept valid visas in expired passports.  So while that might be something to consider for another destination, it does not appear to be relevant for Canada.